# grep a long (~2000) list of different patterns over a huge file (~1 million records)

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, grep

i have a file downloaded in csv format in with nearly 1 million records like below from database dump, Over which i have another file grep_types.sh performs thousand of different combinations of grep. Can anyone tell me how do below operation in bash or python in config + function style (as maintaining file like grep_types.sh is a headache)

db_details.csv

```
permalink,company,numEmps,category,city,state,fundedDate,raisedAmt,raisedCurrency,round
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD,b
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD,a
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD,c
mycityfaces,MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD,seed
flypaper,Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD,a
infusionsoft,Infusionsoft,105,software,Gilbert,AZ,1-Oct-07,9000000,USD,a
gauto,gAuto,4,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,250000,USD,seed
chosenlist-com,ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Oct-06,140000,USD,seed
chosenlist-com,ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,25-Jan-08,233750,USD,angel
```

and i have file that has few thousand of grep line like below (i use a extra operation cat file at start, to make the whole file bit tidy and easy to understand)

grep_types.sh

```
cat db_details.csv | grep ',5,' | grep -v ',angel$' > /tmp/type1.csv
cat db_details.csv | egrep -i ',LifeLock,|gauto' | grep -i 'may' | grep -iv 'dec' >> /tmp/type2.csv
```

looking for a better way/suugestions to handle such operation :)

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I suggest you replace the `grep` script with one `awk` script which can do all these in one scan of the file and save a lot time.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i have a working solution grep_type.sh in place, but the problem is it is untidy and difficult to maintain such a way, for a new type of grep combination i end up writing grep combinations to grep_type.sh

Comment: Have you considered using a `sqlite3` database? Load the csv once and then query to your hearts content. Way faster...

Comment: Well, the fact that you think that it's untidy is not really a problem. That it's tedious to maintain isn't either. However, I kind of understand why you would wish to implement it in a different language, like AWK or Python. Still, why don't you just start with a tutorial of either language? Your question is completely non-specific!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you replace the grep script with one awk script which can do all these in one scan of the file and save a lot time.

For example

```
grep ',5,' | grep -v ',angel$' > /tmp/type1.csv
```

can be (my interpretation)

```
$ awk -F, '$3==5 && $NF!="angel" {print > "/tmp/type1.csv"}
           # other conditional statements 
           # ...
           ' db_details.csv
```

one additional benefit is you can set targeted field conditions as in `$3==5` instead of searching all of the line and getting possible false positives.

Comment: typically the db_dump i perform grep over has near about 215 columns and ~1 million rows
and multiple grep pattern can be  piped together selecting a value from any column (i have ~2500 line of grep combinations that greps from file and dump to ~1200 files )


so awk will be bit of a pain

Comment: just the contrary, `awk` will be your salvation.  You can selectively switch for each different output file.  During the process I won't be surprised if you uncover many hidden bugs. I won't be surprised either if `awk` comes up 100x-1000x faster.

Comment: Also, if you're going to dismiss `awk` solutions, why did you tag your question with `awk`?